# Real-time messages notifications with WPF + WCF

Tags: wpf, wcf, websocket, socket.io, signalr

Hey I'm trying to upgrade notifications service that uses task polling to see if there are new messages for a given interval.
My client is a WPF application and WCF in the server side.
I have 2 application servers with windows server 2008 r2 and load balancer between them.
I thought of implementing it with WCF Duplex binding and noticed it will be a problem to manage my users in 2 service instances (since I can subscribe user only to 1 service).
The trigger for sending messages is when data is manipulated by a user and is related to other specific users.
Another important point is that we plan to scrap our wpf application and revise our front end as web project (with angularjs probably..) and our backend from wcf to .net web api.
I read a bit about push techniques and came to this conclusion:

- SignalR - the thing is, how will it work with web? (angular.js instead of asp.net)
- Wamp - didnt find much about it but it looks promising
- Websockets

  1. .NET implementation (requires IIS 8 which means upgrading our servers)
  2. socket.io - simple and great documentation and community. but I'm not familiar with nodejs.

What are your thoughts about how to implement it?
Thanks, Bar

Comment: SignalR has a javascript client. One of the transports SignalR supports is websockets - you just don't have to deal with websockets directly - the server still has to be able to handle websockets. If the server does not support websockets the client will use server sent events or long polling (or forever frame in case of javascript) transports.

Comment: And what if I know for sure that the server supports web sockets?
and the client is not a browser and they all have .net4

Comment: AFAIK websockets are not supported on .NET Framework 4